# Can someone please explain CMTime for iOS4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I would like to use AVPlayer Class' [seekToTime](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime%3a). It takes a CMTime. I read the CMTime reference from Apple but its is very hard to understand. Can someone please give me an example on how to use...

```
- (void)seekToTime:(CMTime)time
```

Answer (score 5):

Some example are provided in the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_Playback.html) such as:

```
CMTime fiveSecondsIn = CMTimeMake(5, 1);
[player seekToTime:fiveSecondsIn];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rod. I have read the above before and also have tried it. But again, the documentation is not very clear at all. If you actually understand it, could you please explain a little bit?

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding?

Comment: Lets see here, with the above code for example. Is it suppose to fast foward my current track 5 secs ahead? Can I just make it an IBAction and on TouchUpInside skip 5secs aheard for example?